# How to force Focus on Child Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to Focus on a Form.

I tried in Form2:

```
//... 

var form3 = new Form3(this);

if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[form3.Name] == null)
{
    form3.Show();
}

else
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[form3.Name].Focus();
}
```

and then in Form3:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form2 _emailForm;
    
    public Form3 (Form2 emailForm)
    {
        _emailForm = emailForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    public void foo()
    {
        _emailForm.ForceFocus(); 
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

But the Form is never Focused.
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Open a form and focus it?!

Comment: Open form3 from form2, do something in form3 and focus form2.

Comment: Greetings; What are you trying to achieve? / Why do you need to Focus on the Form?
Is there anything that ain't working?
Best regards;

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it like this:

```
public Form1(Form parent)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _parent = parent;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_parent != null)
        _parent.Focus();
}
```

I hope it answers your question. Otherwise please leave a comment.

**EDIT**

Both `Show()` and `BringToFront()` are using `SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(...)` internally. So you won't notice any difference. However, I think it is more common to use `Show()` or `Activate()` on `Form` objects, and `BringToFront()` on `Control` objects, that are part of other `Control` objects.

Comment: There's also `_parent.BringToFront();` or something close to that. Im not at my PC so no VS here. Try intellisense to find it. I'll check it out once i get home.

Comment: Confirmed there is a BringToFront method for a form.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want the user to take action in Form2 prior to being able to utilize Form1 again use .ShowDialog() instead of .Show()